# How to put cursor in the right position after switching from normal mode to insert mode in terminal

Tags: terminal, insert-mode

After launching a terminal inside vim via `:terminal`, vim doesn't put curosr in the right position after pressing `i` in normal mode. As seen in the following picture, the cursor is put at the end of the line while I expected it to be placed right after "word2".

[image: cursor not in the right position when switching from normal mode to insert mode]

How can I tell vim to behave as I have expected?

Answer (score 2):

`:terminal` runs another process (program). That process has its own cursor. When you enter terminal-normal mode, you control Vim's cursor, not the program's one. And after you return to terminal-insert you're again talking to that program and moving its cursor. So this is absolutely expected and works as it should.

Comment: I see. But what if I want vim to sync the launched process's cursor position with vim's cursor postion? Sometimes I need to modify a command in the terminal, so I want to jump right to the expected position after switching from terminal-normal mode to terminal-insert mode.

Comment: @Coiby You can modify picture on screen, but you can't modify process' internal state from Vim. This is nonsense. Terminal-normal is intended for yanking text into Vim, not for anything else.

Comment: The background is I want to use vim' terminal to replace tmux or other terminals so copy and paste among terminals would be very easy. So I still need the help of vi mode in bash/zsh to move the 2rd cursor.